# I can't get multiple items to appear as selected in Navigation Drawer for Android

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app for the local bus system and I'm trying to use the navigation drawer to act as a filter for the routes that appear on the map. The functionality is there, but I'm struggling with the UI. Whenever I click on an item, everything else is set as unchecked, which is not what I want. I've been trying to find a solution for this issue, but didn't come up with anything. Here is the code for the navigation drawer:

MainActivity:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // listen for navigation events
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



    // set up the hamburger icon to open and close the drawer
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
    final boolean enable;
    //update highlighted item in the navigation menu

    //menuItem.setChecked(!menuItem.isChecked());
    if(menuItem.isChecked()){
        menuItem.setChecked(false);
        enable = false;
    }
    else{
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        enable=true;
    }

    //menuItem.setChecked(true);
    mNavItemId = menuItem.getItemId();

    // allow some time after closing the drawer before performing real navigation
    // so the user can see what is happening
    // mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerActionHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            navigate(menuItem.getItemId(),enable);
        }
    }, DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS);
    return true;
}
```

and the layout file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/filter_routes"
    android:title="@string/filter">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/red_route"
            android:title="@string/red_route"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
            android:checked="true"
            android:checkable="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/blue_route"
            android:title="@string/blue_route"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:checked="true"
            android:checkable="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/green_route"
            android:title="@string/green_route"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:checked="true"
            android:checkable="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/orange_route"
            android:title="@string/orange_route"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:checked="true"
            android:checkable="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/brown_route"
            android:title="@string/brown_route"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:checked="true"
            android:checkable="true"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm having the same problem and almost all SO search results are how to single check items.

Comment: I gave up on this and implemented a workaround where a dialog box popped up.

Answer (score 0):

I got multiple selections to work by returning false from onNavigationItemSelected().  From the Google docs for this return value of onNavigationItemSelected():

> boolean   true     to display the item as the selected item

Apparently, this means that returning false leaves item selection in your control.

Here's an example.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="All">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:checkableBehavior="all"
                android:id="@+id/checkable_group"
                >
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/checkable_item_1"
                    android:title="A" />
                <item
                android:id="@+id/checkable_item_2"
                android:title="B" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/checkable_item_3"
                android:title="C" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/checkable_item_4"
                android:title="D" />
        </group>
    </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Code:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.isChecked()) {
            item.setChecked(false);
        }
        else {
            item.setChecked(true);
        }

        return false;       // VERY Important to return false here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I submitted [a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37140133) about this and it was closed as working as intended.  Google apparently made `NavigationView` use menu XML with no intention of having it work like a menu.